# How to change css of a div with a certain id when hovering over a certain element anywhere in the whole webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose there is a div with id "hello". It has a certain css such as display:none;. I want it to change to display:block; whenever hovering over a certain element such as li no matter where in the webpage that element is, with whatever class or id, with whatever css or javascript it is associated with, in whatever container that element is, whatever the id or class of that container, whether it is inside another element such as a li inside a p, whether there is another element inside it such as a p inside a li,...........etc

As long as it is in the webpage, I want it overcome all obstacles and absolutely always  work.

But I can't figure out the jquery for this so please help thanks in advance.

Comment: nope not what I want

Comment: How do you identify the "certain element" to hover over?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that this is your `<div>` element:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#AAAAAA">
  <!-- Your div content here -->
</div>
```

Now you have to add this javascript:

```
// Change color of div on hover
function hover() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = "#FFAAAA";
}

// Return the color back to original when the mouse leaves the li
function retorg() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = "#AAAAAA";
}

var lists = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
// Add event handlers to the li elements
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
  lists[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
  lists[i].addEventListener("mouseout", retorg);
}
```